# What are best practices for maintaining/testing (mostly Perl) software in separate git repositories with dependencies between them?

Tags: perl, git, git-submodules

I am working on refactoring a large (mostly Perl) codebase. Rather that put everything into one giant git repository, I'd like to group related modules and their tests into separate git repositories, and to have the repositories structured like CPAN distributions.

One problem is that if each repository has a distinct CPAN distribution tree, then it seems awkward to use submodules, since (for testing purposes) what we really want is to include each submodule's "lib" in the tests.  This is a minor issue, and I am already aware of various easy workarounds ("use lib..." in tests), but I would like to know what other developers do in similar situations, and what are considered best practices.

A more important issue is how to deal with branching. If a new branch of the submodule is created, and then the branch is updated, how can I test the code in the super-repositories that depend on it for *that branch*? (I may not necessarily want to make changes to the super-repositories, just check that changes to the submodule didn't break anything.)

On a similar note, are there utilities that can track dependencies between git repositories, so that I can determine which super-repositories need testing for a branch after changes to a dependency?

Answer (score 1):

As the software is already CPAN-ready, [simply declare the test deps](http://p3rl.org/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#PREREQUISITES) in the distro meta file. In other words, **think in terms of distributions, not repositories/branches**. I think you're lacking something like CPAN::Mini or DPAN, and a process of packaging and injecting the distros.

A branch should increase the version number, possibly using an underscore number or using the `-TRIAL` distro name to indicate a non-stable release.

Answer (score -1):

The `PERL5LIB` environment variable could be used to avoid adding temporary `use lib`  statements to your scripts. [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Use lib is a minor issue. (And PERL5LIB isn't useful in taint mode, so it would not be useful for me anyhow.)